# Convertion from String to Integer

Tags: java, html, jsp

I have in a HTML code:

form
        input type="text" name="ad4" value="9"
        input type="submit" value="Test EMAIL"
    form (angle brackets taken off on purpose)

Then my JPS code:

```
        String test =  request.getParameter("ad4");
        int testb = Integer.parseInt(test);
        out.print("Your test is: " + test);
        out.print("Your Test conversão é: " + testb);

    %>
```

It Gives an error message: HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page

Comment: and the html code is inside a form and the method is post

Answer (score 1):

You must check jar file or maven.

The following is working correctly.

index.jsp

```
<form action ="show.jsp" action="GET" >
    <input type="text" name = "ad4" value="9" >
    <input type="submit" value="Test">
</form>
```

show.jsp

```
    String test =  request.getParameter("ad4");
    int testb = Integer.parseInt(test);
    out.print("Your test is: " + test);
    out.print("Your Test conversão é: " + testb);
%>
```

Comment: Thanks. It works fine now because the HTML form is in another JSP page. But what if I want the HTML code and JSP code to be in the same JSP page? In that case it gives a 500 -ERROR